# Awk to remove and move rows/records to another file where 3rd field value is empty

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I have below pipe separated pipe.
I want to remove the rows where 3rd field is blank in file1 and need to paste those removed line from File1 into another File(File2).

I tried the below code it is working fine and removing the rows for all three column where 3rd field is blank but not able to figure out how to paste those removed line in another file along with the below code.
So need to know single code statement to remove rows where 3rd column value is empty from File1 and paste those removed rows into another File(like File2)

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS"|" '$3!=""' File1.txt > test.txt
```

File1

```
billingtype|documentnumber|originaldocumentnumber
YMNC|420075416|765467
YMNC|429842808|74646464
YPBC|429842809    
INV|430071605|7688888
YPBC|430071609
```

Output File

```
billingtype|documentnumber|originaldocumentnumber
YMNC|420075416|765467
YMNC|429842808|74646464
INV|430071605|7688888
```

File2

```
billingtype|documentnumber|originaldocumentnumber
YPBC|429842809    
YPBC|430071609
```

Comment: Since you are making `|` as field separator that is why it is not working, see my solution for same now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN  {FS=OFS="|"}
       FNR==1 {print > "File2"} 
              {if($3!="") print; 
               else print > "File2"}' File1 > tmp && mv tmp File1
```

header will be printed in both files.  Output to a temp file and move over to the input file. Missing field records will be printed to other file.

Comment: i got the correct data in File1 with your code..but in File2 i got data for both the rows where 3rd field is blank and not blank..however expectation is to have only data for rows in File2 where 3rd field is blank(that we have removed from File1)

Comment: hi..thank you..it worked now..got the result as expected.. @Karakfa

Answer (score 0):

You can try this gnu sed

```
sed -i -Ee '1{WFile2' -e 'b' -e '}' -e '/(.*\|){2}/!{W File2' -e 'd}' File1
```